# Lie algebra as algebra of derivations

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is an abstract Lie group, then one defines the Lie algebra as the tangent space $T_eG$ at the identity. I understand $T_eG$, to be exactly the derivations of functions defined on neighborhoods of $e \in G$.

Concretely though I don't really see what happens. For example, if $G = SL(n)$ then all matrices with trace zero form the Lie algebra, but in what sense are these derivations? And why don't the matrices with nonzero trace act as derivations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $SL(n)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$, it's easier to just think about vectors.

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ is just the set of vectors based at the identity that are tangent to $SL(n)$; that is, the tangents to curves in $SL(n)$. If $M: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to SL(n)$ is a curve with $M(0) = e$, then we have $\det M(t) = 1$ for every $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. Differentiating this at $t=0$ (using e.g. Jacobi's formula) gives $\operatorname{tr}(M'(0))=0$; so any tangent vector $\xi \in \mathfrak{sl}(n)$ must be a trace-free matrix.

Since the trace-free matrices form a vector space of dimension $n^2-1=\dim SL(n) = \dim \mathfrak{sl}(n)$, we must conversely have that every trace-free matrix based at the identity is in to $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$.

Comment: @user95274: if you don't have an embedding of the group into $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ then it doesn't even make sense to talk about Lie algebra elements as matrices. You only get such concrete realizations of the lie algebra by starting with a concrete realization of the group.